# OData - two navigation properties

Tags: odata

I'm struggling with finding a way to create a valid OData query. I have some data about projects that I can to limit to projects of a specific category involving a specific company.
The Project class has two relevant navigation properties: Companies and Categories. There is no direct link between a Company and a Category.

I've tried queries similar to:

```
test.com/OData/Companies(345)/Projects/Categories(78)

test.com/OData/Companies(214453)?$expand=Projects,Projects/Categories&$select=Projects
```

But the first one fails because a collection has to be the last segment of the request URI, and the last doesn't limit the results by a specific category. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in V2 version of OData. V3 will bring any/all operators which should allow you to write a filter like that. This is for example described as a proposal here: http://www.odata.org/blog/even-more-any-and-all
You can give it a try, it should work in the latest CTP: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx